# Create Color from rgb Stringin Java

Tags: java, android, android-api-levels

This is my code to convert a String to Color:

```
public Color prepareColour(String str) {
    str.replace("#", "");
    float r = Float.valueOf(str.substring(0,1));
    float g = Float.valueOf(str.substring(2,3));
    float b = Float.valueOf(str.substring(4,5));
    Color color = Color.valueOf(r,g,b);
    return color;

}
```

I get the following debug error:

> Error:(16, 23) error: constructor Color in class Color cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: no arguments
>   found: float,float,float
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

However, the suggestion before compiling from Android Studio is:

> Call requires API level 26 (current min is 17) ......

I see there are answers from 2011 supporting this way of creating a Color, so surely it works on API 17 and doesn't require 26.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, as well as replacing the `str.substring` with actual values and nothing changes.

Why will the code not compile?

Comment: Can you provide an example string that you are parsing?

Comment: Submersed, it does not compile. I have replaced the str.substring() with "FF" and it's the same

Comment: the only `Color.valueOf(?)` Method i could find is the one in JavaFX. In case it is, just use `Color.valueOf(someHexString)` and it should work fine

Comment: @TomK https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(float,%20float,%20float)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using `Color.rgb(r,g,b)` instead of `Color.valueOf(...)`?  `Color.valueOf(...)` is a very new method in the Android Developer O preview, so it will only be useful on 1 API level at the moment.

Also, make sure you're using ints in the range of 0-255, or floats in the range of 0-1.

Comment: Not sure why but this way I get the following error: Error:(20, 32) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Color. I am not even using any int...

Comment: Color.rgb returns an int.  An int is a Color, the Color class is just a convenience class for manipulating colors.

Comment: Incompatible types: Required android.graphics.Color ; Found int

Comment: Make your method return an int, and just return Color.rgb(...);  All methods on Color are static, so you don't really need a object of type Color.  You just need the int representation of the Color.

Comment: So methods can't return Color basically. I have to make the conversion when I need to use the Color, right?

Comment: Yep, methods don't return Color just int.  Any API that takes a color will be expecting it in int form, the Color class is just helpful for making those ints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code.

```
Color.parseColor(String strColor);
```

This is a static method of `Color` class

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

Comment: This is the best solution for the question